# Creating linked list of strings

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I am new to data structures as well as to linked lists.
I am working on project named as *Amazon product availability checker using tree in C*. So I want to store strings in each node of the tree but while storing strings the code is not showing any error but the output is also not getting printed. I have pass the node to print function to print the string but nothing is getting printed.

I have shared the code for one string and one node only. I am working on ubuntu and I am coding in the C language.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
    char clothing[10];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// 1) creating node

node *create(char const ch[]) {
    int i;
    node *head = NULL;
    node *temp = NULL;
    node *p = NULL;
    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->clothing[10] = ch[10];
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

// 2) print 

void print(node *head) {
    node *p = head;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%s", p->clothing);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    node *head = create("clothing");
    print(head);
}
```

Comment: The most appreciated way of showing code here is a [mcve]. You present more of a code puzzle. Also, it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Please learn about indentation and comments. Both would help to make your code more readable and less fractured.

Comment: In `create`, `temp` and `p` are unused, so delete them.  And use `strcpy` to copy the string.  `temp -> clothing[10] = ch[10]` is assigning a single character, and in fact that character is out of bounds so you are corrupting memory.

Comment: @TomKarzes can you just elaborate your answer. It will mean a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Review how to copy a string. `temp->clothing[10] = ch[10];` copies the 10th (non-existant) character of `ch` to the 10th index in `temp->clothing`.

Comment: @chqrlie Yeah sure....I was not knowing how to accept answer on stack overflow....thanks!!

Comment: @ALMASSANGLE: you will be able to upvote the answers once you get enough reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `create` function is incorrect:

- you do not test for potential `malloc` failure
- you do not copy the string, but merely cause undefined behavior by attempting to write to `clothing[10]` which is beyond the end of the array. By the way, you read `ch[10]` which may well be out of bounds too. You should instead copy the string, while avoiding a buffer overflow if `ch` is too long.

Here is an improved version:

```
#incude <string.h>
#incude <stdlib.h>

node *create(char const ch[]) {
    temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (temp != NULL) {
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->clothing[0] = '\0';
        strncat(temp->clothing, ch, sizeof(temp->clothing) - 1);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Since C99, there is a way to allocate a copy of the string without a limitation on its size, and without the need for a separate allocation and a pointer in the `node` structure. It is called a flexible array. Here is how it works:

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    char clothing[];
} node;

node *create(char const ch[]) {
    size_t size = strlen(ch) + 1;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(node) + size);
    if (temp != NULL) {
        temp->next = NULL;
        memcpy(temp->clothing, ch, size);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie Thank you so much!! It worked very well. It means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> I have pass the node to print function to print the string but nothing is getting printed.

doing

> ```
> temp -> clothing[10] = ch[10];
> ```

you write (and may be read) one character out of the string, the max index in `temp -> clothing` is 9

you want something like

```
strcpy(temp -> clothing, ch);
```

but take care to not go outside the field *clothing* because *ch* is too long

so can be

```
strncpy(temp -> clothing, ch, sizeof(temp -> clothing) - 1);
temp -> clothing[sizeof(temp -> clothing) - 1] = 0; /* useful if strlen(ch) >= 10 */
```

---

are you sure you do not want to replace `char clothing[10];` by `char * clothing;` to not have that limit to 10 ?

Comment: Please do not advocate the use of `strncpy`, this function is widely misunderstood and causes countless bugs in production code. BTW, you do not need the test in your code, just force the terminator. See this: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Comment: when using it properly it works as expected ;-) But I encourage the OP to not use a constant array size but a `char*` ^^ yes the test to add the term is useless

Comment: Maybe, but most programmers I have met, in person or online, do not use it properly. Its behavior is counter-intuitive, not to mention inefficient. Did you know it pads the destination array with nulls to the size passed as the third argument?

Comment: @chqrlie to pad can be useful, and indicates is not the right way if the constant size is large but again a char * is better. Personaly I think I **never** used strncpy for me :-)

Comment: The padding is almost always useless, as is the case in this particular example. This function was first used in the early Unix system to copy login information to a kernel structure. The login names were limited to 6 letters then, and space was at a premium, so omitting the null terminator was a way to save memory. It should never have made it to the C Standard, but was part of the original C library and people used it, mostly incorrectly from day one.

Comment: If you insist on using `strncpy`, you could pass `sizeof(temp->clothing) - 1` as the size argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
node *addnode(node *after, const char *str)
{
    node *nptr;

    nptr = malloc(sizeof(*nptr));
    nptr -> partstr = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    /* error checking you need to add after every malloc */
    strcpy(nptr -> partstr, str);
    if(!after)
    {
        nptr -> prev = NULL;
        nptr -> next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        after -> next -> prev = nptr;
        nptr -> next = after -> next;
        after -> next = nptr;
        nptr -> prev = after;
    }
    return nptr;
}
```

Comment: your function doesn't correspond to the struct _node_ of the OP, there is no `char*partstr;` nor _prev_ link

Comment: But is better :)