# Building a Linked List of Strings

Tags: c, data-structures

I had a singly linked list that took in integers successfully, but now I want to use strings. However it is not working. I am getting so many different errors about "casting". I am finding conflicting information online as well. One comment here, [Creating linked list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550666/creating-linked-list-of-strings), said not to use strcpy, but I see strcpy used in a few examples online.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char value[];
    struct node* next; // pointer of structure type
};

// set existing type, node, to the alias, node_t
typedef struct node node_t;


node_t *create_new_node(char value) {

    // create space for node with malloc
    node_t *result = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    // set the value of the new node
    result->value = value;

    //strcpy(result->value, value);
    // set the value's next pointer to null

    result->next = NULL;
    return result;
}

node_t *insert_at_head(node_t **head, node_t *node_to_insert) {

    node_to_insert->next = *head;
    *head = node_to_insert;
    return node_to_insert;
}

//Prints linked list
void printlist(node_t* head) {
    node_t *temporary = head;

    while (temporary != NULL) {
        //print out the value of the node that temporary points to

        // printf("%d - ", temporary->value);
        // to move along the list
        temporary = temporary->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {

    node_t *tmp;
    // declaring head pointer
    node_t *head = NULL;

    // CREATING LINKED LIST
    // for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    //     tmp = create_new_node(i);
    //     // sending the address of the head variable
    //     //calling by reference
    //     //SINCE HEAD IS ALREADY A NODE POINTER
    //     insert_at_head(&head, tmp);
    // }
    printlist(head);
    
    tmp = create_new_node("I like food");
    insert_at_head(&head, tmp);

}
```

How can I get this Linked List of string to work?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-Wall`? The compiler is your friend!

Comment: Your `create_new_node()` function takes a `char` as its argument when it should take a `char *`

Comment: @ggorlen No, never heard of it. I will check it out. Thank you.

Comment: @CormacO'Brien why would it need a start? Previously I had it set to "int value" and it worked. Do chars operate differently?

Comment: @ColorfulCodes the difference is that an `int` is a single value, whereas a string (`char []` or `char *`) is a series of values. Dynamic arrays in C, like `char value[]`, are just syntactic sugar for `char *value`, where the pointer points to the first value in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reorganize it a bit, you will be able to allocate the space  the struct & the place for the string in the single malloc.

```
struct node 
{
    struct node* next; // pointer of structure type
    char value[];
};

// set existing type, node, to the alias, node_t

typedef struct node node_t;


node_t *create_new_node(const char *value) 
{
    // create space for node with malloc
    node_t *result = malloc(sizeof(*result) + strlen(value) + 1);
    if(result)
    {
        strcpy(result->value, value);
        result->next = NULL;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use your compiler! I ran `$gcc -Wall a.c` on this code and got:

```
a.c:7:10: error: flexible array member not at end of struct
     char value[];
          ^
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:67:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘create_new_node’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     tmp = create_new_node("I like food");
     ^
a.c:15:9: note: expected ‘char’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 node_t *create_new_node(char value) {
         ^
a.c:70:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Now we know what the problems are. Firstly, `char value[]` should be `char *value` since it's a pointer rather than a flexible array member (FAM). You could also move the FAM to the end of the struct if you want as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62648707/6243352).

Next, `node_t *create_new_node(char value)` is relying on a `char value` when you really want a string, `char *value` for the parameter. There are issues beyond this: you'll likely want to make a copy of the string for the node in case it disappears from the stack. This memory should be cleaned up after use.

Other tips:

- Avoid noisy, redundant comments like:

  ```
    // declaring head pointer
    node_t *head = NULL;
  ```
- `malloc(sizeof(*name_of_the_var));` is safer than `malloc(sizeof(node_t));` if the data changes.
- `node_t *insert_at_head(node_t **head, node_t *node_to_insert)` modifying its parameter *and* returning it is a little unusual. I'd make it `void` to make the in-place contract explicit.
- Alphabetize and remove unused imports.
- Check that `malloc` calls succeeded.
- Remember to `return 0;` from main.
- `typedef struct node node_t;` is okay but also hides info--I prefer keeping the `struct` there.

Here's a possible rewrite:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char *value;
    struct node* next; 
};

struct node *create_new_node(char *value) {
    struct node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

    if (!node) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d malloc failed\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        exit(1);
    }

    node->next = NULL;
    node->value = strdup(value);

    if (!node->value) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d malloc failed\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        exit(1);
    }

    return node;
}

void insert_at_head(struct node **head, struct node *node_to_insert) {
    node_to_insert->next = *head;
    *head = node_to_insert;
}

void print_list(struct node *head) {
    for (; head; head = head->next) {
        printf("%s->", head->value);
    }

    puts("");
}

void free_list(struct node *head) {
    while (head) {
        struct node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp->value);
        free(tmp);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char n[16];
        sprintf(n, "%d", i);
        insert_at_head(&head, create_new_node(n));
    }

    print_list(head);
    free_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
9->8->7->6->5->4->3->2->1->0->
```

Comment: 1. No malloc result checks. 2. Completely not needed expensive strcat. And it is only one function.

Comment: Yes, good calls. What do you mean by "it is only one function"?

Comment: Did not analyse it further\

Comment: Updated, let me know if anything looks wrong to you.